# Как сменить фон формы по клику на её элемент?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Для программы нужна смена фона и размера окна
Текущий код:

```
    private: System::Void новичокToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
    {
        //9*9
        this->Height = 360;
        this->Width = 300;
        this->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"$this.BackgroundImage")));
        this->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Stretch;

    }
```

Так как строки были взяты с кода самой формы подвязка картинки вызывает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как пользоваться этой функцией не заходя в свойства элемента ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел подходящее решение

```
pictureBox1->Image=Image::FromFile(FileName);
```

Формат адреса (вариант ввода FileName)

```
C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\name.png
```